# Weak derivative different from the classical one.

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, weak-derivatives

If $f \in C^k(\Omega)$, with $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open and such that $\partial \Omega$ is regular, than by Gauss-Green formulas, we can show that the classical $\alpha$ derivative $D^\alpha f$ of $f$ coincides with the distributional one, for all $\alpha$ multi index s.t. $|\alpha| \le k$.
Does it exist a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, with $n>1$, differentiable but **not continuously differentiable** s.t $D^\alpha$ is integrable but it doesn’t coincide with the distributional one?

In other words, does it exist a Sobolev function (defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n>1$) whose distributional derivative do not coincide with the classical one?

Comment: You don't necessarily need continuity to apply the Gauß-Green formula

Comment: @stange, do you mean that in the Gauss Green formula I can replace the hypothesis $f\in C^k(\Omega)$ with the simple differentiability of $f$?

Comment: That wouldn't be enough, but I think integrability of $D^\alpha f$ suffices (even weak differentiability should work)

Comment: @stange in $1D$ if $ f \in C^1(\Omega / \{x_0\})$ and $f' \in L^1_{loc}$ than the weak derivative is given by
$$\left(\frac{d}{dx} f,\varphi\right)= \int\left( f'(x) + (f(x_0^+)-f(x_0^-))\delta_{x_0}\right) \varphi(x) dx $$ so you need at least continuity of the function $f$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Weak and classical derivatives: an overview](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3294660/weak-and-classical-derivatives-an-overview)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Marco, but actually it is not exactly what I was wondering, because in 1D I know that to have the integrability of the distributional derivative the function should be absolutely continuous. Probably the best way to ask what I mean is asking it as I do in the edited body of my question.